# use OpenCV with Clion IDE on Windows

Tags: windows, opencv, clion

I'm actually looking for a way to create apps with OpenCV with Clion from JetBrains.

I've installed OpenCV with Choco, so I have all the stuff in C:\opencv

this is my projet with Clion

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
include_directories("C:\\opencv\\build\\include\\")

FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED core highgui imgproc)
set(OpenCV_FOUND TRUE)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(prog ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

and the main.cpp:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main() {

    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("./test.jpg", -1);
    cv::imshow("Mon image", img);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

and the response to build is :

```
undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
```

and undefined errors for all OpenCV functions

Do you know why it doesn't works?

Comment: have you set your environmental variables? What compiler are you using? You're not linking your executeable against the OpenCV_LIBS

Comment: any love for `macos` environments?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

First of all, you need [CMake](https://cmake.org/download/).
Then you need a compiler of your choise ([MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/), [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/de/downloads/), ...).

1. Download the OpenCV source files. [Link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv)
2. Unpack to `C:\opencv` (or a folder of your choice)
3. Open `CMake` and select source (directory of **2.**) and build for example `C:\opencv\mingw-build` or `C:\opencv\vs-x64-build`. Choose one accoring your configuration.
4. Click `Configure` and select the generator according to you compiler. `MinGW Makefiles` in case of MingGW or `Visual Studio ...` if you are using Visual Studio and so on ...
   (If you experience problems with MinGW, ensure that the minGW/bin directory is added to the evironment path labelled, 'PATH')
5. Wait for the configuration to be done, edit your properties of your needs (in my case I don't need tests, docs and python).
   [image]
   Click `Configure` again. When everything is white click `Generate` else edit the red fields.
6. Open `cmd` and dir to build directory of **3.**
   If you chose Visual Studio open the generated solution.
7. Compile the library. Run `mingw32-make` (or `mingw64-make`) or build the `BUILD_ALL` project from the generated solution in Visual Studio if your choosen compiler is MSVC.
   **This takes a while.**
   [image]
8. Once it is done, run `mingw32-make install` (or `mingw64-make install`). If you've choosen Visual Studio you need to build the `INSTALL` project.
   This creates an install folder, where everything you need for building your own OpenCV apps is included.
9. To system `PATH` add `C:\opencv\mingw-build\install\x86\mingw\bin`
   **Restart your PC.**
10. Set up CLion:

    - You need to download [FindOpenCV.cmake](http://code.opencv.org/attachments/196/FindOpenCV.cmake) and add it to `project-root/cmake/`.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

# Where to find CMake modules and OpenCV
set(OpenCV_DIR "C:\\opencv\\mingw-build\\install")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(test_cv main.cpp)

# add libs you need
set(OpenCV_LIBS opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_highgui opencv_imgcodecs) 

# linking
target_link_libraries(test_cv ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cv::Mat frame;
    frame = cv::imread(argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file

    if(!frame) // Check for invalid input
    {
        std::cout << "Could not open or find the frame" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cv::namedWindow("Window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); // Create a window for display.
    cv::imshow("Window", frame); // Show our image inside it.

    cv::waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

Build and run `main.cpp`.

All Paths depend on the setup you make in **2.** and **3.** You can change them if you like.

**UPDATE 1:** I updated the post for using a compiler of you choice.

**SUGGESTION:** Using a package manager like [Conan](https://conan.io/) makes life much easier.

Comment: Above you state, "You need to download FindOpenCV.cmake and add it to project-root/cmake/."  In my case, I needed to add FindOpenCV.cmake to CLion's CMake installation directory, which in my case was at `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 2016.2.1\bin\cmake\share\cmake-3.6\Modules`.  In this location I find many other `Find*.cmake` files.

Comment: Can I use this with Cygwin in CLion instead of MinGW while building opencv with MinGW, as in CMake-gui there isn't Cygwin

Comment: @MichałZiobro Yes you can.

Comment: Why i am getting continuosly errors about undefined references to cvRound() founction? I tried prebuild libraries in opencv extracted packege and also other cygiwn precompiled packege from some website. I have also tried to compile it with CMake gui but it continuously fails to compile with some errors like invocations of some thread realated functions. It seems very hard to get it working on windows ;/ i am porting app from macOS and don't think it will be so hard to make it working correctly.

Comment: I tried to run it with Cygwin, but constantly saw multiple errors, then installed MiniGW and all worked like a charm.

Comment: Did anyone have a problem when executing `cingw32-make`? I did everything exactly by the guide, but it throws error like this:

```opencv\sources\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jmemmgr.c: In function 'realize_virt_arrays':

\opencv\sources\3rdparty\libjpeg-turbo\src\jmemmgr.c:662:11: error: 'SIZE_MAX' undeclared (first use in this function)
       if (SIZE_MAX - maximum_space < new_space)
           ^~~~~~~~
```

Any idea, please? I am not really c++ developer.

Comment: Im getting `C:\opencv\3rdparty\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\stubs\io_win32.cc:330:10: error: '::_wfopen' has not been declared
   return ::_wfopen(wpath.c_str(), wmode.c_str());` error ON step 7, anyone ideas what to do here?

Comment: I made all of this and I add this [FindOpenCV.cmake](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2f4e38c8313ff313de7c41141d56d945d91f47cf/cmake/OpenCVConfig.cmake) (your link is dead) in the project and in the folder
*C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.2.1\bin\cmake\win\share\cmake-3.17\Modules*

But I have :
> Found OpenCV Windows Pack but it has no binaries compatible with your configuration. You should manually point CMake variable OpenCV_DIR to your build of OpenCV library.


My PATH is : *C:\tools\opencv\build\install\x64\mingw\bin* ; *C:\Program Files\CMake\bin*

Comment: link to FindOpencv.cmake is broken

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add one more thing in the answer of **daB0bby**. Few Min-GW Compilers do not support C++ Version 11 or later. This version is required for thread in OpenCV. So I will suggest using [TDM-GCC Compiler](https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/) instead of MinGW Compiler. Install this compiler and set path **C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin** to the system's environmental variable.

Answer (score 0):

While you can build it like the answer by daB0bby, as he suggests at the end of his post a package manager is way more convenient.

In fact, Vcpkg is actually built into Clion.

In New UI you have to click `View`->`Tool Windows`->`Vcpkg` then add an instance with the + sign and find OpenCV.