# Failed to compile OpenCV project with Clion IDE

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, mingw, clion

I configured OpenCV 3.4.11 according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36422689/13348864).

I am using **MingGW** as my compiler.

Here is what **CMake GUI** told me:

```
Detected processor: AMD64
sizeof(void) = 4 on 64 bit processor. Assume 32-bit compilation mode
libjpeg-turbo: VERSION = 2.0.5, BUILD = opencv-3.4.11-libjpeg-turbo
Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES) 
LAPACK requires BLAS
A library with LAPACK API not found. Please specify library location.
Found apache ant: C:/apache-ant-1.10.8/bin/ant.bat (1.8.0)
Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
OpenCV Python: during development append to PYTHONPATH: D:/mingw-build-3.4.11/python_loader
Caffe:   NO
Protobuf:   NO
Glog:   NO
freetype2:   NO
harfbuzz:    NO
Module opencv_ovis disabled because OGRE3D was not found
No preference for use of exported gflags CMake configuration set, and no hints for include/library directories provided. Defaulting to preferring an installed/exported gflags CMake configuration if available.
Failed to find installed gflags CMake configuration, searching for gflags build directories exported with CMake.
Failed to find gflags - Failed to find an installed/exported CMake configuration for gflags, will perform search for installed gflags components.
Failed to find gflags - Could not find gflags include directory, set GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing gflags/gflags.h
Failed to find glog - Could not find glog include directory, set GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing glog/logging.h
Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Eigen Glog/Gflags
Allocator metrics storage type: 'int'
Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.avx2.cpp
Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/resize.avx2.cpp
Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.avx2.cpp
Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.avx512_skx.cpp
Excluding from source files list: modules/features2d/src/fast.avx2.cpp

General configuration for OpenCV 3.4.11 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            D:/opencv_contrib-3.4.11/modules
    Version control (extra):     unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2020-08-15T06:52:46Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.18363 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.18.1
    CMake generator:             MinGW Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe
    Configuration:               Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2
      requested:                 SSE2
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16
      SSE4_1 (14 files):         + SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (5 files):             + SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++11:                       YES
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Strawberry/c/bin/g++.exe  (ver 4.9.2)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  C:/Strawberry/c/bin/gcc.exe
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--gc-sections  
    Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--gc-sections  
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          comctl32 gdi32 ole32 setupapi ws2_32 winmm
    3rdparty dependencies:       libprotobuf zlib libjpeg-turbo libwebp libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf quirc

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dpm face features2d flann fuzzy hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
    Disabled:                    python_bindings_generator python_tests world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv freetype hdf java js matlab ovis python2 python3 sfm viz
    Applications:                apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI: 
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.11)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.0.5-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.10)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (ver 57.107.100)
      avformat:                  YES (ver 57.83.100)
      avutil:                    YES (ver 55.78.100)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 4.8.100)
      avresample:                YES (ver 3.7.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES

  Parallel framework:            none

  Trace:                         YES (built-in)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                D:/opencv-3.4.11/sources/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python (for build):            C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe

  Java:                          
    ant:                         C:/apache-ant-1.10.8/bin/ant.bat (ver 1.8.0)
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    D:/mingw-build-3.4.11/install
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Configuring done
```

After applying `mingw32-make -j8` and `mingw32-make install` in **CMD**, it built successfully.

Then, I add `D:\mingw-build-3.4.11\install\x64\mingw\bin` to my System **PATH** and restarted my computer.

The **step 10** tells me to download [FindOpenCV.cmake](https://code.opencv.org/attachments/196/FindOpenCV.cmake) and add it to project-root/cmake/. However, this link responsed **502 Bad Gateway**, thus I jumped over this step.

The following is my project contents:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(opencv)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")
# Where to find CMake modules and OpenCV
set(OpenCV_DIR "D:\\mingw-build-3.4.11\\install")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core highgui imgproc imgcodecs)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(opencv opencv.cpp)
# add libs you need
set(OpenCV_LIBS opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_highgui opencv_imgcodecs)
# linking
target_link_libraries(opencv ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

**opencv.cpp**

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main() {
    Mat mat = imread("1.jpg");
    imshow("1", mat);
}
```

CMake build successfully like following:

```
"D:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.1.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" D:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Codes\CLionProjects\opencv
-- OpenCV ARCH: x64
-- OpenCV RUNTIME: mingw
-- OpenCV STATIC: OFF
-- Found OpenCV 3.4.11 in D:/mingw-build-3.4.11/install/x64/mingw/lib
-- You might need to add D:/mingw-build-3.4.11/install/x64/mingw/bin to your PATH to be able to run your applications.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Codes/CLionProjects/opencv/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]
```

However, everytime I run this application, compiler keeps telling me:

```
====================[ Build | opencv | Debug ]==================================
"D:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.1.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build D:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Codes\CLionProjects\opencv\cmake-build-debug --target opencv -- -j 4
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable opencv.exe
CMakeFiles\opencv.dir/objects.a(opencv.cpp.obj): In function `main':
D:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Codes/CLionProjects/opencv/opencv.cpp:6: undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
D:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Codes/CLionProjects/opencv/opencv.cpp:7: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
CMakeFiles\opencv.dir/objects.a(opencv.cpp.obj): In function `cv::String::String(char const*)':
D:/mingw-build-3.4.11/install/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:602: undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long long)'
CMakeFiles\opencv.dir/objects.a(opencv.cpp.obj): In function `cv::String::~String()':
D:/mingw-build-3.4.11/install/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:648: undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
CMakeFiles\opencv.dir/objects.a(opencv.cpp.obj): In function `cv::String::operator=(cv::String const&)':
D:/mingw-build-3.4.11/install/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:656: undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
CMakeFiles\opencv.dir/objects.a(opencv.cpp.obj): In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
D:/mingw-build-3.4.11/install/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:786: undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
CMakeFiles\opencv.dir/objects.a(opencv.cpp.obj): In function `cv::Mat::release()':
D:/mingw-build-3.4.11/install/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:898: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\opencv.dir\build.make:91: opencv.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:75: CMakeFiles/opencv.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/opencv.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: opencv] Error 2
```

Actually no error founded in code check. Moreover, I can find the `imread` source code through click function with **CTRL** button pressed.

Comment: If `mingw32-make install` finished succesfully, why do you need the other steps?

Comment: @Yunus Temurlenk I just followed the steps in the link I provided. (step 8)

Answer (score 0):

After building OpenCV with MinGW-w64 I usually do this:

```
INSTALLPREFIX=installation_path_supplied_as_CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX
cp -f build/unix-install/*.pc $INSTALLPREFIX/lib/pkgconfig/
mkdir -p $INSTALLPREFIX/share/OpenCV
mv $INSTALLPREFIX/*.cmake $INSTALLPREFIX/share/OpenCV/
```

That usually helps get OpenCV to get detected.