# Use OpenCV/CMake with Clion

Tags: opencv, installation, cmake, clion

I wish to use CLion for my course so I follow this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36422689/12285201).

I updated my PATH by adding these values :

- C:\Program Files\CMake\bin
- C:\tools\opencv\build\install\x64\mingw\bin

(I use chocolatey)

And I added this [FindOpenCV.cmake](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2f4e38c8313ff313de7c41141d56d945d91f47cf/cmake/OpenCVConfig.cmake) to my project and in the folder *C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.2.1\bin\cmake\win\share\cmake-3.17\Modules*.

When I try to reload my project in CLion I have :

> Found OpenCV Windows Pack but it has no binaries compatible with your configuration. You should manually point CMake variable OpenCV_DIR to your build of OpenCV library.

How can I solve that ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you might have two CMakes installed. Which one are you actually using when running CLion?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my environnement use this : 
MinGW : *C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64* ; CMake : *C:\Program Files\CMake\bin*

Comment: Yes, but it appears CLion is using CMake that may be located here `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.2.1\bin\cmake\win\share\cmake-3.17`